# cryptor.decrypt(encryptedPassword, key) giving unexpected result

Tags: flutter, dart, cryptography

I am using the `flutter_string_encryption` package in flutter.

The issue is, when I try to return or print the decrypted password, I am getting `Password that you want to encrypt` everytime instead of the expected output which is the decrypted password.

Code :

```
import 'package:flutter_string_encryption/flutter_string_encryption.dart';

class PasswordDecrypter {
  getDecryptedPassword(String encryptedPassword, String key) async {
    late PlatformStringCryptor cryptor;

    String decryptedS = 'null';
    try {
      cryptor = new PlatformStringCryptor();
      print('encrypted password --> ${encryptedPassword}');
      print('key --> ${key}');
      decryptedS = await cryptor.decrypt(encryptedPassword, key);
      print(decryptedS);
    } on MacMismatchException {}
  }
}
```

Output:

```
flutter: encrypted password --> kvuiY8XZijdow55NJK/rDw==:aPXdiqlgLQ1OMk4gMt3SR9vBmPc3VVw33b49RJcZmGY=:qgiT1ER4l3BCSbRktRB4LgFRPWVxn72pgvgwMyop8nu9fj7b1UEYAsAUkJAmrJr+
flutter: key --> 75Jt+M+zwmMwIKlciQPXgQ==:N7RvOLZw8r+s/v9iyIi064HcToynOSsQgDtB4yhd47Y=
flutter: Password that you want to encrypt
```

Comment: *Password that you want to encrypt* is simply the decrypted plaintext.

Comment: S. [here](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=From_Base64('A-Za-z0-9%2B/%3D',true)AES_Decrypt(%7B'option':'Base64','string':'75Jt%2BM%2BzwmMwIKlciQPXgQ%3D%3D'%7D,%7B'option':'Base64','string':'kvuiY8XZijdow55NJK/rDw%3D%3D'%7D,'CBC','Raw','Raw',%7B'option':'Hex','string':''%7D,%7B'option':'Hex','string':''%7D)&input=cWdpVDFFUjRsM0JDU2JSa3RSQjRMZ0ZSUFdWeG43MnBndmd3TXlvcDhudTlmajdiMVVFWUFzQVVrSkFtckpyKw) for the decryption and [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_string_encryption/latest/flutter_string_encryption/PlatformStringCryptor/encrypt.html) for the meaning of the parts.

Comment: Thanks @Topaco, it solved my query.